# 16-bit two's complement number

Tags: binary, twos-complement

The question is
What are two's complement numbers of the following 16-bit numbers?

> 1.0x3f9d

My answer is:

> 0011111110011101 in binary because 0x3f9d is a positive number.

However, some people said that the answer is:

> 1100000001100011

I am confusing because `1100000001100011` is a negative number. Which one is the right answer?

Comment: `0011111110011101` is correct.What's this got to do with C though?

Comment: If the input is positive, the result of negation is surely negative. (though the reverse is not necessarily true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3F9Dh is a positive number, equal to 0011 1111 1001 1101 binary. It only makes sense to speak of two's complement when a number is negative.

You might be confusing the term two's complement presentation (of a number) with the algorithm "calculate two's complement of x". If you would calculate the two's complement of 3F9Dh, you would indeed end up with 1100 0000 0110 0011.

In C you could do this calculation as

```
(uint16_t)~0x3F9D + 1
```

which is equivalent to

```
(uint16_t)-0x3F9D
```

(assuming two's complement CPU and not some exotic nonsense CPU)